# Retrofit. Wait for firebase token before making real network call?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, retrofit

I have recently built a proxy in my google cloud that authenticates a user. In my app, I get a firebase token that I get at start up.
The firebase token is returned in a callback. How can I make sure that code finishes before I make my retrofit call and add the token to the header with every call?

Googled a lot but no success so far

Comment: Kinda hard to answer this with no code, can you not add a loading screen in your app until you have the token.

Comment: I do have that. I guess it's more an issue with my widgets since they can restart whenever and I'm not 100% the user is logged in at all times there. A firebase token is only valid for 1 hour so I need to make sure it's always checked before each network call

Comment: Can you not retrieve a token only for that widget? Depending on your auth structure you can limit the scope to only what you need

Comment: Preferably I would like to make it as generic as possible, like an await to get the token before making the real network call because I have one retrofit class that makes all the calls.

Comment: You can have multiple instances of your api